# How to run php code from file_get_contents

Tags: php

I have a file **template.php**:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{title}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="header">
            <h1>This is header</h1> 
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <h1>This is content</h1>
            <?php $this->showContent(); ?>
        </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <p>Copyright &copy; <?= date('Y'); ?> by My Company.</p>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and in file **controll.php**, code look like this:

```
$file = file_get_contents('template.php');
echo $file;
```

but it not run php script `$this->showContent();`.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: you `include` a code file, and not use the output of `file_get_contents`

Comment: This is so basic. You probably want to read the PHP manual before asking this.

Comment: it seems it might be using a template engine. Do you know how `{title}` is supposed to be replaced?

Comment: i'm use file_get_contents because i want to change {title} to dynamic title

Comment: and why would you use `file_get_contents` to replace `{title}` why not just use a php variable?

Answer (score 4):

you should try

```
require_once('template.php'); // will execute the page as php
```

What **file_get_contents** will do is read the file as some kind of textfile and return the value of it. That's not what you want. **require_once.php** will include the php file and handle it as php. This would be similar as having the code in the file you are including it in.

Comment: This answer is correct, however a little explanation of why to use this will improve the quality of this answer